# query ID# and GPA by students most recent term

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble with one part of a larger query. I need to get a students most recent GPA at the end of the year. This is determined by the most recent term they attended class. GPAs are stored in the database by a term summary and not a rolling gpa. I'm having issue with grabbing the most recent term entry for each student. My query is below and I need to know how to pull the most recent gpa, but the most recent term each student attended that year. FYI I'm working in sql server.

```
SELECT s.id,
   Max (t.terms),
   Max(t.gpa),
   Sum(s.credits)   AS systemCredits,
   Sum(s2.credits)  AS DegreeCredits,
   Sum (s3.credits) AS trans_in
 FROM   (SELECT *
    FROM   student_courses
    WHERE  ( course_code IN ( 'a', 'b', 'c' ) )
           AND grade IN ( 'a', 'b', 'c' )) s
   FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT *
                    FROM   student_crs_hist
                    WHERE  ( course_code IN ( 'a', 'b', 'c' ) )
                           AND grade IN ( 'a', 'b', 'c' )) s2
                ON s.id = s2.id
                   AND s.years = s2.years
                   AND s.terms = s2.terms
   JOIN (SELECT *
         FROM   stud_term_sum_div
         WHERE  years = '2013'
                AND terms = (SELECT Max(terms)
                             FROM   term_sum
                             WHERE  years = '2013')) t
     ON s.id = t.id
  GROUP  BY s.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Without fully understanding the challenges that your data model might pose, I would recommend  splitting this up into multiple queries.

The first query should determine the most recent semester attended per student and store it in some place convenient, like a table variable

```
declare @recentSemester 
table (semesterId int
       , studentId int)

insert into @recentSemester
select 
    studentId
    , max(semesterId)
from student_courses sc
left join student_crs_hist sch
    on sc.id = sch.id
where sch.course_code in ( 'a', 'b', 'c' )
  and sch.grade in ( 'a', 'b', 'c' )
group by studentId
```

The second query should join this table variable directly against the table that stores your semester GPA's and perform any aggregations.